# Magento loses session data

Tags: session, magento

I use the following to set some data:

`Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('amprevnext_collection_ids', array_values($ids));`

it contains an array of ids,

when trying to retrieve the data

`Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('amprevnext_collection_ids')`

it does not return any value, I tested by trying to change the core to customer,
I also used a `$_SESSION`, which in return was empty as well..

Comment: At what point in an execution are you setting and retrieving this data?

Comment: Try just Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setAmprevnextCollectionIds(arra('key' => 'value');

Comment: it is called after the catalog product is loaded, catalog_product_collection_load_after

Comment: did try the Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setAmprevnextCollectionIds(array('key' => 'value')); it seems the session is rewritten again after it is set when navigating to another page but only partialy